# Draw a circle through 4 points on parabola

Tags: plotting, graphics, geometry, intersection

I have two dynamic perpendicular parabolas: $y=ax^2+c, x=by^2+d$, which intersect in four points (the coefficients are chosen that way). There is a fact that we can construct a circle through these four points.

My question is which command allows to construct a circle through four points?

Comment: [Three points determine a circle.](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ThreePointsDetermineACircle/)

Comment: yes, and i can graph it. But because of the machine accuracy being nonezero it can pass near the fourth point

Comment: @Michael Freimann If you edit your post to include the smallest and nicest (indented four spaces to let SE know this is code and not to be desktop published) bit of code, NOT a screenshot image, that shows your two parabolas with sliders then someone else might take a few minutes to try to write a couple of lines of code that would try to fit the best circle onto your four points.

Comment: "There is a fact that we can construct a circle through these four points." - there's a constructive proof of that statement; why not use *Mathematica* to work through it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is a motivating post. I have made no effort to deal with intersection <4 pts.
I post only illustrative examples.

The centre of the circle is the intersection of perpendicular bisectors of chords.

```
f[a_, b_, c_, d_] := 
 Module[{e1 = a x^2 + b, e2 = c y^2 + d, s, p, l, ln, ctr},
  s = Solve[{x, e1} == {e2, y}, {x, y}, Reals];
  p = {#, a #^2 + b} & /@ N[x /. s];
  l = Partition[p, 2, 1];
  ln = InfiniteLine[{(#1 + #2)/2, (#1 + #2)/2 + Cross[#2 - #1]}] & @@@
     l;
  ctr = RegionIntersection @@ ln[[{1, 2}]];
  ParametricPlot[{{x, e1}, {e2, y}}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[p], Black, Dashed, ln, 
     Green, ctr, Purple, Thick, 
     Circle[ctr[[1]], Norm[ctr[[1]] - p[[1]]]]}, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   PlotLabel -> Row[{"{", e1, ",", e2, "}"}]]]
```

Examples:

```
Grid[Partition[
  f @@@ {{1, -2, 1, -2}, {1, -3, -1, 3}, {1, -4, 1, -2}, {-1, 2, 
     1, -3}}, 2]]
```

[image]

I reiterate I have made no effort to deal with number of intersections <4.

Comment: ...and of course, `Circumsphere[]` is built-in, and works in 2D. :)

Comment: @J.M. Thanks...didn't know that...always learning. :)

Comment: It's a convenient function, but I think your approach is more pedagogically appropriate for the OP.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a standard algebraic approach, to complement [@ubpdqn's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1997/ubpdqn) geometric one.

If we have a sequence of points $(x_i,y_i)$, $i=1,2,\dots,n$ lying on a circle, then the linear system
$$A\,(x_i^2+y_i^2)+B\,x_i+C\,y_i+D=0,\quad i=1,2,\dots,n$$
will have a nontrivial solution $(A_0,B_0,C_0,D_0)$.
If there are at least three distinct points not on a line, the solution space will have dimension 1 and the circle through the points will be unique.

Here is a function that will find the intersections of curves and see a circle runs through the points.

```
ClearAll[circleIntersect];
circleIntersect::nocirc = "There is not a unique circle through the points.";
circleIntersect[eqs_, vars : {_, _}] := 
 Module[{circle, mat, form, res},
  form = {vars.vars, Sequence @@ vars, 1};       (* {x^2+y^2, x, y, 1} *)
  mat = form /. Solve[eqs, vars, Reals];         (* NSolve is often much faster *)
  Check[                   (* Dot::dotsh, Set::shape errors if null space not 1D *)
   {circle} = Sow[NullSpace[mat], "basis"].form; (* make basis available via Reap *)
   res = circle == 0,
   Message[circleIntersect::nocirc];
   res = $Failed
   ];
  Sow[mat[[All, {2, 3}]], "points"];             (* make points available via Reap *)
  res /; FreeQ[res, $Failed]
  ]
```

#### Examples

**Two parabolas** intersecting in four points.

```
p1 = y == x^2 - 4;
p2 = x == 2 y^2 - 3;
{eq, {pts}} = Reap[circleIntersect[{p1, p2}, {x, y}], "points"];
If[FreeQ[eq, circleIntersect],
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@{p1, p2, eq}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point@pts}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`Solve` will return points in terms of `Root` objects.  If there is a nice form for the solution, `FullSimplify` might find it:

```
eq // FullSimplify
(*  2 (x^2 + y^2) == 11 + x + 2 y  *)
```

**Tangent parabolas** require some care.  In this case if the machine real `4.` is replaced by the exact integer `4`, `Solve` runs for longer than I'm willing to wait.  Numeric error with the machine-precision `4.` leads to nonzero imaginary parts in the solution; hence the use of `Chop` below.  One could replace `4.` by the arbitrary-precision `` 4.`16 ``, which would lead to a zero imaginary part.

```
p1 = y == x^2 - 4.;
p2 = x == y^2 - Root[16411 - 1152 #1 - 4096 #1^2 + 256 #1^3 &, 2];
{eq, {pts}} = Reap[circleIntersect[{p1, p2}, {x, y}], "points"];
If[FreeQ[eq, circleIntersect],
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@{p1, p2, Chop@eq}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point@pts}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eq
(*
  (0.960573 + 9.29229*10^-16 I) + (0.16052 + 1.32742*10^-14 I) x +
     (0.16052 - 1.06369*10^-14 I) y - (0.16052 - 6.13072*10^-15 I) (x^2 + y^2) == 0
*)
```

**Points not lying on a circle.**
This intersection of a parabola and a quartic does not define a circle.

```
p1 = y == x^2 - 4 - x^4/16;
p2 = x == 2 y^2 - 3;
circleIntersect[{p1, p2}, {x, y}]
If[FreeQ[%, circleIntersect],
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@{p1, p2, %}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**More than one circle.**
This intersection of two parabolas has only two points and does not define a unique circle.

```
p1 = y == x^2 - 4;
p2 = x == 2 y^2 - 1;
{eq, {{{pts}}, {{basis}}}} = 
  Reap[circleIntersect[{p1, p2}, {x, y}], {"points", "basis"}];
pts // N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note, one could detect this.  The basis returned `NullSpace` consists of two vectors. Linear combinations of these parameterize all the circles through the two points of intersection.

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@{p1, p2}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, ContourStyle -> Black],
 ContourPlot[  (* family of circles *)
  Evaluate[
   Table[{(1 - t^2)/(1 + t^2), (2 t)/(1 + t^2)}, {t, 1.8^Range[-8, 8]}] . 
    N@basis.(List /@ {x^2 + y^2, x, y, 1})], 
  {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4},
  Contours -> {{0}}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: beautiful...+1  of course :)